# Azure Sentinel PublicIP associations/disassociation logs

Tags: azure-sentinel

For the purposes of alerting when something has happened concerning a public IP, for example, a Public IP address was associated with a resource (NIC, Load Balancer, etc.), shouldn't this work?

```
AzureActivity
| where OperationNameValue == @"Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/join/action"
```

It is the literal definition from MS, here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ip-services/virtual-network-public-ip-address

Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/join/action - Associate a public IP address to a resource

but yet, the event (me, associating a public IP to a VM's nic) shows up under "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/write"

My question is, what is the Operation that I need to evaluate for if I want to see if a Public IP was associated/disassociated with a resource (regardless of the resource)?

Ideally not just associations and dissassociations, but also creation, deletion, etc.

These do seem to work:

@"Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/read", @"Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/write", @"Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/delete" but I care most about associations and dissassociations.

Thanks!

UPDATE TO THIS ISSUE:
After some digging and speaking with Azure support, my original thought of using:

```
Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/join/action
```

won't work, because it's not an alertable action!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations

[image]

To accomplish alerting in Sentinel/Log analytics for an operation where a public IP has been associated or disassociated from a resource, let's say a VM, the alert has to target:

```
Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/write
```

Essentially, the public IP association/disassociation is a "write" operation that's **resource dependant** so, you have to look at the operation name that corresponds to the resource you can actually associate/disassociate a public IP with:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ip-services/public-ip-addresses#at-a-glance

I will update this thread with an actual kql query that can be used as a baseline later on.

Answer (score 1):

so there are 2 ways you could accomplish this,

one being what you have suggested above, using the `Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/write`and creating a sentinel analytic for this

the other way is to create a general email alert, see the below link for guidance

https://www.amdhservicesltd.com/monitoring-azure-public-ip-address-creation

unfortunately there's no real way to alert for association or disassociations as of yet